# How to put question mark after a quotation mark (in Chicago or MLA style)?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, quotation-marks, question-mark

For example, if I want to ask a question that says:

> Where is, "You know nothing, Jon Snow"

should I punctuate it as

> Where is, "You know nothing, Jon Snow?"

or

> Where is, "You know nothing, Jon Snow."?

or

> Where is, "You know nothing, Jon Snow,"?

Comment: You left out a possibility, which is correct for the usual American style: *Where is, "You know nothing, Jon Snow"?*

Comment: This would be better at [writers.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because style guide questions are out of our scope here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chicago Manual of Style (CMOS)

> **6.70 Question marks in relation to surrounding text and punctuation**
>
> A question mark should be placed inside quotation marks, parentheses,
> or brackets only when it is part of (i.e., applies to) the quoted or
> parenthetical matter.
>
> *The ambassador asked, “Has the Marine Corps been alerted?”*
>
> *Why was Farragut trembling when he said, “I’m here to open an inquiry”?*

If you are writing a lot and need guidance, I'd suggest paying $30/year to get a subscription to the [**Chicago Manual of Style**](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org), including its very useful forum. The headaches caused by **not** having it are considerable.